# Visual studio data-bind attribute highlighting [knockout.js]

Tags: visual-studio, knockout.js, syntax-highlighting

In previous versions of Visual Studio I've had knockout.js syntax highlighting.

Since moving to Visual Studio 2017 Community building in Razor however, the syntax highlighting is gone and I found no way to enable it.

Interesting is however, that when I put the very same code into project built on Webforms, the highlighting seems to work at least to some degree

Is there anything I can do to enable syntax hightlighting for Razor? And/Or is there a way how to make custom syntax highlighting rules? [e.g. highlight specific data attribute, or so]

[image: Syntax highlighting comparison when building Webforms and Razor project]

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Also Read the overview.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-madsk.RazorLanguageServices

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately. VS tells me I already have the extension. I went as far as reinstalling whole Visual studio, but still can't get the knockout syntax highlighting to work

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in our Project we added the file reference on the **_references.js** file:

```
/// <reference path="knockout-3.4.0.debug.js" />
```

This make Visual Studio **Intellisense** to get the sintax hightlighting on the .cshtml files.

> **Reference Directives**
>
> A reference directive enables Visual Studio to establish a relationship between the script you are currently editing and other scripts. The reference directive lets you include a script file in the scripting context of the current script file. This enables IntelliSense to reference externally defined functions, types, and fields as you code.

**Sources:**

[MSDN - JavaScript IntelliSense](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385682.aspx#JavaScript%20IntelliSense%20Features)

[C# Corner - Use of _references.js File](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/use-of-referencesjs-file-in-asp-net-mvc-project)

[Mads Kristensen - The history behind _references.js](https://madskristensen.net/blog/the-story-behind-_referencesjs/)